# Ajax conflict with Lesti FPC

Tags: magento-1.9, full-page-cache

I have Manadev ajax layered navigation extension and Aheadworks Ajax cart pro extension. They both work fine when Lesti FPC is disabled. But they seem to have some conflict when FPC is enabled. Ajax cart pro ajax loader is triggered when I select a filter from layered navigation. Any guidance on this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's because of the same cache keys begin used for both the standard and ajax page.
To prevent this turn of the cache when the page is loaded with Ajax.

Create a small custom module with the following files
`app/code/[pool]/[Namespace]/[Module]/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <[Namespace]_[Module]>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </[Namespace]_[Module]>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <[namespace]_[module]>
                <class>[Namespace]_[Module]_Model</class>
            </[namespace]_[module]>
        </models>
        <events>
            <controller_action_predispatch>
                <observers>
                    <[namespace]_[module]_controller_action_predispatch>
                        <class>[Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Observer</class>
                        <method>processPreDispatch</method>
                    </[namespace]_[module]_controller_action_predispatch>
                </observers>
            </controller_action_predispatch>
        </events>
    </global>
</config>
```

`app/code/[pool]/[Namespace]/[Module]/model/Observer.php`

```
class [Namespace]_[Module]_Model_Observer
{
    public function processPreDispatch(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $action = $observer->getEvent()->getControllerAction();
        $isAjax = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('is_ajax');

        // Check to see if $action is a Category controller
        if ($action instanceof Mage_Catalog_CategoryController && $isAjax == '1') 
        {
            $cache = Mage::app()->getCacheInstance();
            $cache->banUse('full_page'); // or whatever is the tag for this cache type
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You were fast this time. I was about to close this.

Comment: Ran into this a few weeks back ;) Common issue with modules using Ajax and FPC

Comment: no need for any modules or events, plus the banUse(full_page) won't work with *Lesti FPC* - the question is about Lesti FPC, not the enterprise FPC.

Comment: @Cristi as I said, you might have to edit the cache tag to suit the specific FPC module. And using params will work in most cases but clearing all of the results will remove all params and result in the same url is the page which will cause the issue again

Comment: ok, i missed that code comment. and I don't understand what you meant in the second sentence. a.html is not the same as a.html?param=1 (if param is specified in the configuration of lesti fpc).

Comment: In several layered navigation extensions clearing out all filters will give an ajax URL without any params which will, again, cause the caching issue. That's way params in the Lesti configuration might not always work. I'm not sure for all navigation extensions but i've encountered the issue on a couple of shops

Comment: ok, got it now. so they're sending the ajax request as post. well, that might need some extra work indeed.

Comment: @SanderMangel Thanks so much. I can understand what you are saying. I am not a developer. Can you please help me out? Do I create a directory like this app/code/[pool]/[Namespace]/[Module]/etc/config.xml

Comment: @Haya you'll need to create a module for this. Check http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/01/basics-creating-magento-module/ for more information about this

Comment: problem doesn't seem to go away. below is what appears in the log file. 2015-01-08T18:38:42+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: array_key_exists() expects parameter 2 to be array, null given  in /html/app/code/local/AW/Ajaxcartpro/Model/Renderer/Confirmation/Addproduct.php on line 46

Comment: please help. issue disappears when FPC is turned off

Answer (score 4):

actually, there's a good post about this: https://gordonlesti.com/lestifpc-and-layered-navigation/

you have to either disable fpc for ajax requests or cache all ajax requests based on the filter parameters.

Comment: How do we disable FPC for ajax requests? I am having trouble with Amasty Layered Navigation

Comment: if there's an ajax or isAjax parameter, use that. however, you should see why requests get cached in the first place - don't they use a custom route? if so, adjust your cacheable handles

Comment: I add is_ajax to URl params. Its working now :-)